# Consistency of different ways to define the tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products

It seems my trouble with understanding tensors stems from the following statement:

[image]

More specifically, the statement:

[image]

Namely, given $B: V \times W \to U$ and $\xi: U \to \mathbb{R}$,

$\xi \circ B: V \times W \to U \to \mathbb{R}$. 
and we have $v \otimes w: (V \times W)^* \to \mathbb{R} $

So how does this all combine to give a linear map $ \beta: V \otimes W \to U$?

How does this define a linear map from the dual of $U$ to the space of bilinear forms?
 What is meant by the last sentence: "The dual map... $U$"?
Any other thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Given B from V x W to U, define beta from V tensor W to U** by beta(v tensor w)(eta)= eta o B (v,w).

Comment: If $\beta(v \otimes w)(\eta) = \eta \circ B(v,w)$, how does $v \otimes w$ act on $\eta$ if $\eta \in U^*$ not $\eta \in (V \times W)^*$? and $\eta \circ B(v,w): V \times W \to U \to \mathbb{R}$ so how does this correspond to $\beta: V \otimes W \to U^{**}$?

Comment: $ \beta(v\bigotimes w) (\eta) = \eta o B (v,w) $

Comment: @berkeleychocolate yes but how does $\eta \circ B(v,w)$ give the map from the tensor product to $U$?

Comment: beta, u and v are fixed, eta varies, so beta(u tensor v) maps a member of U* to R, that is belongs to U** which is identified with U via the map x**(f) = f(x).

Comment: what is $u$? Why does $\beta(u \otimes v): U^* \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant v $\bigotimes w. $\eta is in U*, the value of $\eta o B(v,w) is in R. Sorry about my poor latex.

Comment: @berkeleychocolate so let me see if I understand... We have $(v \otimes w) = B(v,w)$ that is, $v \otimes w: B \in (V \times W)^* \to \mathbb{R}$. We then have $\eta \in U^*$, $$\beta (v \otimes w) (\eta) = \eta \circ B(v,w)$$... that is, $\beta: U^* \to \mathbb{R}$ so $\beta \in U^{**}$. But how does this give $\beta: V \otimes W \to U^{**}$ if $\beta \in U^{**}$?

Comment: @berkeleychocolate I seem to be missing something crucial

Comment: beta is not in U**, but beta (v tensor w) is in U** since it maps functions in U* like eta to reals linearly.

Comment: @berkeleychocolate Then how do we go from $\beta(v \otimes w): U^* \to \mathbb{R}$ to $\beta: V \otimes W \to U$?

Comment: @berkeleychocolate I'm missing something, because the way I see it is as $\beta: v \otimes w \in V \otimes W\to \beta(v \otimes w)(\eta) \in U^{**}$

Comment: @berkeleychocolate Moreover how does it "define a linear map from $U^*$ to the space of bilinear forms"? bilinear forms on what?

Comment: The map from eta to eta o B(v,w). Let me just say a few more general things. The mapping property is the key idea, that B's can be replaced by beta's. Loosely speaking this means that  v tensor w isn't so different from v cross w. Nothing has really been added. This mapping property characterizes the tensor product. The maps of maps is just the way this job happens to get done.

Comment: @berkeleychocolate Yes I understand that you've said $\beta ( v \otimes w): U^* \to \mathbb{R}$, but how does that translate to it being the unique linear map $\beta: V \otimes W \to U$?

Comment: @berkeleychocolate I can completely agree that $\beta (v \otimes w)$ takes an element of the dual space of $U$ into an element of the dual space of $V \times W$, namely $$\beta(v \otimes w)(\eta): U^* \to (V \times W)^* \to \mathbb{R}$$, but I don't see how this becomes $\beta: V \otimes W \to U^{**}$

Comment: @berkeleychocolate Oh sh*t. Tell me if I'm correct:  Since $\beta(v \otimes w) \in U^{**}$, this obviously should mean $\beta: V \otimes W \to U^{**}$...The notation is what was really throwing me off..

Comment: @berkeleychocolate I should be thinking about $v \otimes w$ as a map in itself, yes?

Comment: @Anthony Peter: Wherever you have found this "definition", read another book. It's not worth reading it when it defines the tensor product that way. (The definition is 1. conceptually wrong, 2. complicated, 3. not suited to satisfy the univ. prop (that's also the only reason why your question is here)).

Comment: Sorry I quit for last night. beta of v tensor w is the function that  takes the member eta of U* to the real number eta o B(v,w), so it is a  member of U**. Remember that B,v,w are fixed at the moment of this definition. This definition of the tensor product is elegant and tricky. There are other ones which elucidate the tensor product better, for example, as formal sums of products modulo the relations needed to make it into a vector space. This definition is the modern one because it is quick, not because it is clear. I don't have a reference for the other definition, but I know it exists.